# how can i handle invalid document reference error in firestore v9

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i am currently working on chat app , but when i got to the chat component, i have been having this error when i tried submitting the chat into the firestore database that i created with a collection called channels

this is my code below;

```
const sendMessage = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let input = inputRef.current.value;
    if (input !== "") {
      const messagesRef = doc(db, "channels", channelId, "messages");
      const payload = {
        timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
        message: inputRef.current.value,
        name: user?.displayName,
        photoURL: user?.photo,
        email: user?.email,
      };
      await addDoc(messagesRef, payload);
    }
```

when i click on the submit button to create that document i get this error below.

> Unhandled Rejection (FirebaseError): Invalid document reference.
> Document references must have an even number of segments, but
> channels/8jIExW7vKcXJRJdmq9b3/messages has 3.

i have been trying to seek help but i have not gotten since 3 days now.

Comment: Are you sure `channelId` has a value. What does it show when you `console.log(channelId)` right before you use it in `const messagesRef = doc(db, "channels", channelId, "messages");`?

Comment: thank @FrankvanPuffelen. i was able to figure out the solution to this problem. I was ref the doc function instead of the collection function since i was trying to access a sub collection in the db. so all i  needed to do was change this const messagesRef = doc(db, "channels", channelId, "messages"); to const messageRef = collection(db, ...)

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out Paul.  --- It might be worth posting a self-answer, so that devs who land here in the future can more easily see how you solved it.